# How to display DateTimes with am/pm without using custom formatting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Currently I display my `DateTime`s in Rails with:

```
my_time.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)
```

That produces a date like:

```
March 17th, 2014 14:44
```

Perfect except for the `14:44` time. I want it to say 2:44pm (how the 'pm' is formatted doesn't matter to me). This needs to be easier for a common person to read. I know I can use:

```
my_time.strftime('%l:%M %p')
```

However, I'd really like to use a predefined symbol for a more human readable format, because I'd like this to be more human readable in any language. If someone is browsing from a different language where `DateTime`s naturally look a little different, I'm hoping Rails can, or at least be set to, automatically display the `DateTime` nicely. Maybe I'm expecting too much of Rails there? Seems strange to me though that there isn't a simple flag or setting for a more human readable `DateTime` format.

Comment: I'm not really sure, what you mean with more human readable? What's the problem with `2014-04-07 10:37:56 +0200` or `2014-04-07 22:37:56 +0200`?

Comment: @at. I do not think without using strftime, you would get time in that format.

Comment: @user3383458, is that really how you'd respond to a friend who asks, "What day and time is it?"

Comment: Ok. I thing I got your problem.

Answer (score 4):

in that case you can add your own humanized format

```
# config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:custom_long_ordinal] = "%B %e, %Y %l:%M %p"
```

and use it with

```
my_time.to_formatted_s(:custom_long_ordinal)
```

Comment: This doesn't really help answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the api doc reference for ActiveSupport DateTime formatting: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_formatted_s

Comment: I had seen this. Is there something in there that helps answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 10:15 pm

You could use:

```
t=Time.now
am=true
if t.hour >= 12
  t=t-12*60*60
  am=false
end
s=t.to_s[13..17]
if am==true
  return s+ "am"
else
  return s+ "pm"
end
```

Or edit/expand the Time-Class with SOMETHING LIKE (I would not advice you use this code, it's just a draft)

```
class Time
  def self.humanize
    t=self
    am=true
    if t.hour >= 12
      t=t-12*60*60
      am=false
    end
    s=t.to_s[13..17]
    if am==true
      return s+ "am"
    else
      return s+ "pm"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll be better reading up on Rails' [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

---

We format our times using the `config/locales/xx.yml` file:

```
#config/locals/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      small: "%-dM %-dD %-dW"
```

This allows us to call:

`<%=l object, format: :small %>`

You can then use [strftimer](http://strftimer.com/) to get some really nice formatting

Comment: Seems like this is my best bet. Is it possible to get an ordinal day number in the format? Rails handles this with a lambda, but is a lambda possible in a locale string?